# Laravel 5.4 Pusher (laravel-echo) cannot access private channel

Tags: laravel-5, pusher, laravel-echo

I've been testing Laravel Echo and it works fine for non-private channels. I receive the data that gets passed through an event on that non-private channel. But the problem is when I set up the event to broadcast on a private channel I receive an error message as per the below:
Note: I am logged in as a user as per the picture.
[image: Private server error]

As I'm subscribing to a private channel, in Laravel I went to config/app.php and uncommented ' App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class, '.
Also went to App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php and used the code as per the picture below:
[image: BroadcastServiceProvider]

My Resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js file have the following code and compiled using laravel mix:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'hiddenkey',
  cluster: 'ap1',
  encrypted: true
 });

window.Echo.private('chat-room.1')
      .listen('ChatMessageWasReceived', (e) => {
          console.log(e.user, e.chatMessage);
});
```

btw i already installed all dependencies, ie:
- composer require pusher/pusher-php-server ,
- npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js ,
Also configured my config/broadcasting.php using the reference to .env file which have inputed all the information needed for pusher. Everything works fine as you can see for a non-private channel which i receive the data from the event as per the picture below:
[image]

Here is the event i created:
[image: Event]

I am receiving the private channel, event and data as per the picture:
[image]

Why even if i am a signed-in authenticated user, and in the BroadcastServiceProvider.php file i am returning true to the  `Broadcast::channel()` method, i don't see the data passed from my event? i receive data from non-private channel, so why not in a private-channel? What are my doing wrong? why do I get these errors in my console and not the data:

```
- POST http://example.dev/broadcasting/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)
- Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500
```

BTW I was following this tutorial until I got stuck with private channel:
    https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-echo

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is that private channels should have a wildcard. In your Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php, where defining the the authorisation of your private channel, you should place the wildcard of the private channel in ' {} ' . In my case should be as per below:

```
    Broadcast::channel('chat-room.{chatroomId}', function ($user, 
    $chatroomId) {} );
```

Note that even though i defined 'chat-room.1' as the name of my private channel in my event, i still have to use the ' {} ' as per above code for the wildcard and NOT '1', as private channels are supposed to have wildcards. You cannot use * as the wildcard, as was the problem.

Hope it helps anyone.